# How do I generate a pdf file using object/ json data in my nestjs application?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have an object returned from my DB query, which contains some simple key-value pairs and a small sized image. I want to generate a pdf using the object to upload it in my S3 bucket from my nestjs server. How can I achieve that, I searched for npm libraries but they does not seem to be of much help as most of them advice me to first create a html file using my object and then create a pdf from the html and since my object is small, I don't want to go through the lengthy process of first creating a html file and the generating pdf from it.

The object that I have is something like-

```
"finalReport": {
"taskId": "myId",
"report": "all done",
"signatureHandyman": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...",
"notesCustomer": "done",
"signatureCustomer": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...",
"nameCustomer": "Cust",
"createdAt": "2023-03-31T03:14:32.015Z",
"user": {
  "id": "uuid",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "phone": "",
  "name": "Handyman",
  "role": "HANDYMAN",
}
```

I want to show some title and key-value pairs from my object along with the signature images in the pdf.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Puppeteer to generate PDF from HTML string. Just create some function to generate HTML (in string, not file) from your object and pass it to the puppeteer.

```js
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

let puppeteerOptions: puppeteer.PuppeteerLaunchOptions = {};
// config for Alpine linux
puppeteerOptions = {
  headless: true,
  executablePath: "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
  args: [
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--headless",
    "--disable-gpu",
    "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
  ],
};

// config for windows
puppeteerOptions = {
  headless: true,
};

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeteerOptions);

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setContent(
  htmlInString
);

await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
const pdf = await page.pdf({
  format: "A4",
  printBackground: true,
  margin: { top: "45px", right: "45px", bottom: "45px", left: "45px" },
});

await browser.close();

res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
res.setHeader(
  "Content-Disposition",
  `attachment; filename="someName${andMaybeId}.pdf"`
);
```